# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non object on line 15

Tags: php, oop, pdo

could any one please help me to find out the error in this code blog ? the code goes here :..........

```
<?php
include_once('classdatabase.php');

class ManageUsers{
    public $link;

    function __construct(){
        $db_connection= new dbConnection();
        $this->link=$db_connection->connect();
        return $this->link;
    }

    function registerUsers($username,$password){
       // include_once('classdatabase.php');
        $query=$this->link->prepare("insert into users (username, password) VALUES (?,?)");// the error is just noticed this line !
        $values=array($username,$password);
        $query->execute($values);
        $count=$query->rowCount();
        return $count;
    }
}
$users= new ManageUsers();
echo $users->registerUsers('emi','emi');


?>
```

next this is the another PHP class file(classdatabase.php) where i was declared the main Database connection , code goes here:

```
<?php
class dbConnection{
   protected $db_conn;
    public $db_name='todo';
    public $db_user='root';
    public $db_pass='';
    public $db_host='localhost';

    function connect(){
    try{   $this->db_conn= new PDO("mysql:host= $this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name",$this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
        return $this->db_conn;
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
    }
}

?>
```

have got an error , error-

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\Todo\Classes\class.ManageUsers.php on line 15

Comment: I thought it was ground hog day for a second, are you also Red Rose? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29581197/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-prepare

Comment: @chris85 can you please find out the error for me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access your `$this->db_conn`. Try these mods. I have tested it on my own database and it works A-OK. If you have problems still, then you may need to check that you are using the proper connection credentials because the only way this won't work is if the connection fails and returns the error instead of the class (`$this`):

```
class dbConnection
    {
        // Create public connection
        public $db_conn;
        public $db_name =   'todo';
        public $db_use  =   'root';
        public $db_pass =   '';
        public $db_hos  =   'localhost';

        public  function connect()
            {
                try {
                        // Try concatenating your db credentials
                        $this->db_conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->db_host.';dbname='.$this->db_conn,$this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
                        // return $this only
                        return $this;
                    }
                catch(PDOException $e) {
                        // Try exiting and printing the error.
                        print_r($e->errorInfo());
                        exit;
                    }
            }
    }

    class ManageUsers
        {
            public  $link;
            public  function __construct(){
                $db_connection  =   new dbConnection();
                // Assign method chained connection
                $this->link     =   $db_connection->connect()->db_conn;
            }

            function registerUsers($username,$password){
               // include_once('classdatabase.php');
                $query  =   $this->link->prepare("insert into users (username, password) VALUES (?,?)");// the error is just noticed this line !
                $values =   array($username,$password);
                $query->execute($values);
                $count  =   $query->rowCount();
                return $count;
            }
        }

$users  =   new ManageUsers();
echo $users->registerUsers('emi','emi');
```

Comment: showing the same error again :( ...

Comment: Did you make all 3 modifications?

Comment: yes , even i made change to public from protected access modifier

Comment: Ok, well, I just tried what I supplied to you and it connects and writes to the database fine. Did you change it to: `$this->link=$db_connection->connect()->db_conn;`?

Comment: Ok, I have added one more change in the connection. That is the only thing I can think of next to do. What I have posted works, tested on my own database

Comment: thank you @Rasclatt yes i did as like you said , even i copied your code from here :) ., ,,, but its not working yet though i can manually insert data into data base , so i think my connection credentials are OK  , now the new error i get is : Call to undefined method PDOException::errorInfo() in C\wamp\www\Todo\Classes\classdatabase.php on line 20

Comment: Ok so write `print_r($e);` See what it does there.

Comment: PDOException Object ( [message:protected] => could not find driver [string:private] => [code:protected] => 0 [file:protected] => C:\wamp\www\Todo\Classes\classdatabase.php [line:protected] => 15 ........................................
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\Todo\Classes\class.ManageUsers.php on line 15

Comment: You are having a connection error then. You won't get to the error portion unless your connection itself is having a problem.

Comment: The problem was with the versions , yes now its working so well , sorry guys for my ignorance